# Debian init.d with a working C++ daemon, unexpected results

Tags: debian, daemon, c++, init.d

I am fairly new to programming for Linux, and init.d scripts, and I have a problem with my init.d script adapted from an example I found via a lot of google searching. Instead of getting a status, starting or stopping, or restarting, my daemon shows up as another process no matter what I do. The daemon works as expected, adding a syslog entry every minute. Actually, it works when multiples are running, logging an entry at one minute intervals each depending on when they start.

My Daemon 'sbecd'

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

#define DAEMON_NAME "vsbecdaemon"

void process(){

    syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "SBEC Communications Daemon Entry");
}   

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    //Set our Logging Mask and open the Log
    setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_NOTICE));
    openlog(DAEMON_NAME, LOG_CONS | LOG_NDELAY | LOG_PERROR | LOG_PID, LOG_USER);

    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Entering SBEC Communications Daemon");

    pid_t pid, sid;

   //Fork the Parent Process
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    //We got a good pid, Close the Parent Process
    if (pid > 0) { exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); }

    //Change File Mask
    umask(0);

    //Create a new Signature Id for our child
    sid = setsid();
    if (sid < 0) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    //Change Directory
    //If we cant find the directory we exit with failure.
    if ((chdir("/")) < 0) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    //Close Standard File Descriptors
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDERR_FILENO);

    //----------------
    //Main Process
    //----------------
    while(true){
        process();    //Run our Process
        sleep(60);    //Sleep for 60 seconds
    }

    //Close the log
    closelog ();
}
```

My init.d script

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          sbecd
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog $network $mysql
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Seed Bed Environment Control Daemon init.d Script
# Description:       SBEC Daemon init.d control script
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Gary Rubin of HopWorks <myemail>
#

# Do NOT "set -e"

# PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Serial Communications Controller - Seed Bed Environmental Control"
NAME=sbecd
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/$NAME
#DAEMON_ARGS="--options args"
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.2-14) to ensure that this file is present
# and status_of_proc is working.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been started
    #   1 if daemon was already running
    #   2 if daemon could not be started
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
        || return 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
        $DAEMON_ARGS \
        || return 2
    # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
    # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
    # on this one.  As a last resort, sleep for some time.
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
    # Return
    #   0 if daemon has been stopped
    #   1 if daemon was already stopped
    #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
    #   other if a failure occurred
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    RETVAL="$?"
    [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
    # and if the daemon is only ever run from this initscript.
    # If the above conditions are not satisfied then add some other code
    # that waits for the process to drop all resources that could be
    # needed by services started subsequently.  A last resort is to
    # sleep for some time.
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry=0/30/KILL/5 --exec $DAEMON
    [ "$?" = 2 ] && return 2
    # Many daemons don't delete their pidfiles when they exit.
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    return "$RETVAL"
}

#
# Function that sends a SIGHUP to the daemon/service
#
do_reload() {
    #
    # If the daemon can reload its configuration without
    # restarting (for example, when it is sent a SIGHUP),
    # then implement that here.
    #
    start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
    return 0
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_start
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  stop)
    [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
        0|1) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 0 ;;
        2) [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg 1 ;;
    esac
    ;;
  status)
    status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;
  #reload|force-reload)
    #
    # If do_reload() is not implemented then leave this commented out
    # and leave 'force-reload' as an alias for 'restart'.
    #
    #log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
    #do_reload
    #log_end_msg $?
    #;;
  restart|force-reload)
    #
    # If the "reload" option is implemented then remove the
    # 'force-reload' alias
    #
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" "$NAME"
    do_stop
    case "$?" in
      0|1)
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
            1) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Old process is still running
            *) log_end_msg 1 ;; # Failed to start
        esac
        ;;
      *)
        # Failed to stop
        log_end_msg 1
        ;;
    esac
    ;;
  *)
    #echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}" >&2
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

:
```

My processes (filtered) after running 'sbecd start' and then 'sbecd status'

```
~# ps -A | grep sbecd
 3399 ?        00:00:00 sbecd
 3594 ?        00:00:00 sbecd
```

Webmin shows the daemon as set to start at boot but that doesn't happen until I key in 'sbecd ', and 'sbecd stop' has no effect.
I would like to know what I am doing wrong, and why I am seeing the behavior that I am. I have read through numerous tutorials and seen many examples, including this great one by Devin Watson at http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html and was wondering if it is the daemon itself that is affecting the init.d where it is something I missed or set incorrectly.

Comment: Also, your `#include` lines don't look right.  Either they're missing, or aren't properly formatted for this site.

Comment: IUnlessyour daemon creates a pid file, you need to remove the `--pid-file` flag to `stop-start-daemon`.

Comment: I fixed the includes. I started the post with stackexchange scripting blocked, and manually used <pre><code>. It had unexpected results. Sorry. Going after the whole post with code blocks. Should fix, sorry again.

Comment: Should I modify my daemon to create a pid file? All the functions use that variable. Is there a benefit for a daemon to create a pid file or is it a best practice?

Comment: It might be easier to add the `--make-pidfile` option. See http://serverfault.com/questions/160553/init-script-does-not-create-a-pid-file

Comment: *You* have to create the pid file as the process started by the script forks and then exits.  The real question is did you create the `rc?.d` links to the `init.d` script? (`update-rc.d` should do it, but check that it did it correctly)

Comment: I ran update-rc.d on the script and it does show up in rc?.d and I took out the --pid-file flags and added --make-pidfile according to the site mentioned above. No issues and the usual warning when I run update-rc.d. I get 'insserv: warning: script 'functions' missing LSB tags and overrides' and that is it.

Comment: Also as we know that Debian would migrate to systemd, creating that script is a waste of time.